# iOS 6 CLLocationManager last location

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, cllocationmanager, cllocationdistance

So, as of iOS 6, `-locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` is deprecated.

Apple suggests, instead, using `-locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`, which provides anywhere from one to a series of recent location changes. However, in the incredibly likely chance it provides a `locations` array of length 1, there appears to be no way to access the `fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation` parameter of old.

Is there a way to get at this information without using deprecated methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set a property to the value that locationManager:didUpdateLocations: returns, which you can use as the fromLocation, and then call the method again, and use what it returns as the toLocation.

Comment: I assume that when you say "call the method again" you mean wait until the `CLLocationManager` calls it on your behalf.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, although you can control when it gets called somewhat by setting the distance filter.

Comment: Very good. I apologize, therefore, for my rather duplicative answer and have adjusted to give you due credit!

Answer (score 0):

As rdelmar said, if you need the previous location, I would just store the last location received from `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` in an ivar or property, and if `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` returns an array with only one value, grab the value you previously saved in your ivar/property and use that for your "old" location.